# Метасимволы в методе matches

Tags: java

Задача в том, чтобы в строке обнаружить число от 1 до 100. Не могу разобраться, почему нельзя это выразить при помощи  `num1.matches("[1-100]")` 
Работает это только так:  `num1.matches("[1-100]?\\d+")` .

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что диапазон значение обозначаемый как `[...]` определяет правила для сопоставления одного и только одного символа. Таким образом, все, что вы пишете в скобках, указывает, как сопоставить один символ.
Ваш шаблон `[1-100]` будет соответствовать только символам 1 и 0.
Если же вы хотите проверять числа от 1 до 100, то выражение должно выглядеть следующим образом `^[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$`.

Answer (score 0):

Если прочитать вашу регулярку то получится следующее:
"[1-100]?" - указывает, что вы ищете в этом диапазоне (это не так, на самом деле здесь диапазон 1-1) и это значение может быть одно или может отсутствовать
"\d+" - ожидаете что следующий символ будет цифровым один или более раз

Собрав все воедино получится что ваша регулярка будет ловить числа, но все подряд.

["Полезная ссылка на статью по регуляркам"](https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/regulyarnye-vyrazheniya-v-java)

Если коротко, то вот такое выражение можно использовать для поиска 1-999 - "\b\d{1,3}\b"

для поиска 1-399 "\b[1-3]{0,1}[0-9]{0,1}[0-9]\b"

Вообще, считается плохим тоном усложнение кода без необходимости.
Учитывая то, что вы пишете код, можно использовать удобночитаемую регулярку для поиска трехзначного числа в нужном тексте, и обычным сравнением определить, попадает найденное число в диапазон от 1 до 300.

Не усложняйте свой код. Код читается намного чаще, чем пишется.